# Geodesics using Euler-Lagrange

Tags: geometry, calculus-of-variations, integral-equations, geodesic, euler-lagrange-equation

thanks for taking a look at my question.  This is a homework problem from a section covering Euler-Lagrange equations. I'm asked to consider the arc length formula:

$S = \int\limits_{{t_1}}^{{t_2}} {\sqrt {{{\left( {{\textstyle{{du} \over {dt}}}} \right)}^2} + {{\cos }^2}u{{\left( {{\textstyle{{dv} \over {dt}}}} \right)}^2}} dt} $.

Then I'm asked to find the geodesic between two fixed points with respect to the arc length formula, shown above, by choosing $t=u$.  The question also gives a hint that says:

$\int {{\textstyle{c \over {\cos u\sqrt {{{\cos }^2}u - {c^2}} }}}du =  - \arccos } \left( {{\textstyle{c \over {\sqrt {1 - {c^2}} }}} \cdot {\textstyle{{\sin u} \over {\cos u}}}} \right)$, where $c$ is a constant.

So I've substituted $u$ for $t$ to arrive at:

$S = \int\limits_{{u_1}}^{{u_2}} {\sqrt {{{\left( {{\textstyle{{du} \over {du}}}} \right)}^2} + {{\cos }^2}u{{\left( {{\textstyle{{dv} \over {du}}}} \right)}^2}} du \to } \int\limits_{{u_1}}^{{u_2}} {\sqrt {1 + {{\cos }^2}u{{\left( {{\textstyle{{dv} \over {du}}}} \right)}^2}} du} $

Based on the integral obtained after the substitution, would I be correct if I used:

$\frac{d}{{du}}\left( {\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial v'}}} \right) = \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial v}}$, where
$f = \sqrt {1 + {{\cos }^2}u{{\left( {{\textstyle{{dv} \over {du}}}} \right)}^2}} du$ and 
$v' = \frac{{dv}}{{du}}$

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes it is correct, (just make sure that the $du$ isn't included in the $f = \sqrt{1 + cos^2...}$ part)

Comment: Also question, why does your arc length formula include the $\cos^2 u$ it is not euclidean space that you are on?

Answer (score 1):

So the functional you are optimizing here is

$$ \int_{u_1}^{u_2} \sqrt{1 + \cos(u)^2 \left( \frac{dv}{du} \right)^2} du $$

This is expressed as

$$ \int_{u_1}^{u_2} F(u,v, \frac{dv}{du}) du $$

ELE states that this is optimized by finding $v$ that satisfies

$$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial v} - \frac{d}{du} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \frac{dv}{du}}  = 0 \rightarrow \frac{\partial F}{\partial v} = \frac{d}{du} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \frac{dv}{du}}$$

As you correctly noted.

### SPOILER ALERT SOLUTION BELOW:

We can go ahead and solve this equation then, noting that $\frac{\partial F}{\partial v} = 0$, and

$$\frac{d}{du} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \frac{dv}{du}} = \frac{d}{du} \left[ \frac{ \cos(u)^2 \frac{dv}{du}}{\sqrt{1 + \cos(u)^2 \left( \frac{dv}{du} \right)^2}} \right] = -\frac{ 2\sin(u) \frac{dv}{du}}{\sqrt{1 + \cos(u)^2 \left( \frac{dv}{du} \right)^2}} + \frac{ \cos(u)^2 \frac{d^2v}{du^2}}{\sqrt{1 + \cos(u)^2 \left( \frac{dv}{du} \right)^2}} - \frac{ \cos(u)^2 \frac{dv}{du}\left( \cos(u)^2 \frac{dv}{du} \frac{d^2v}{du^2}-  \sin(u) (\frac{dv}{du})^2 \right)}{\left(1 + \cos(u)^2 \left( \frac{dv}{du} \right)^2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

So we are now finding $v(u)$ such that:

$$0 = \frac{ \cos(u)^2 \frac{d^2v}{du^2}}{\sqrt{1 + \cos(u)^2 \left( \frac{dv}{du} \right)^2}}-\frac{ 2\sin(u) \frac{dv}{du}}{\sqrt{1 + \cos(u)^2 \left( \frac{dv}{du} \right)^2}}  - \frac{ \cos(u)^2 \frac{dv}{du}\left( \cos(u)^2 \frac{dv}{du} \frac{d^2v}{du^2}-  \sin(u) (\frac{dv}{du})^2 \right)}{\left(1 + \cos(u)^2 \left( \frac{dv}{du} \right)^2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}} $$

Multiplying out the bottom square root yields:

$$0 = \cos(u)^2 \frac{d^2v}{du^2}-2\sin(u) \frac{dv}{du}  - \frac{ \cos(u)^2 \frac{dv}{du}\left( \cos(u)^2 \frac{dv}{du} \frac{d^2v}{du^2}-  \sin(u) (\frac{dv}{du})^2 \right)}{1 + \cos(u)^2 \left( \frac{dv}{du} \right)^2} $$

Again forming common denominators

$$0 = (1 + \cos(u)^2 \left( \frac{dv}{du} \right)^2)(\cos(u)^2 \frac{d^2v}{du^2}-2\sin(u) \frac{dv}{du} ) -  \cos(u)^2 \frac{dv}{du}\left( \cos(u)^2 \frac{dv}{du} \frac{d^2v}{du^2}-  \sin(u) (\frac{dv}{du})^2 \right)  $$

We reduce the first term:

$$0 = (1 + \cos(u)^2 \left( \frac{dv}{du} \right)^2)(-2\sin(u) \frac{dv}{du} ) -  \cos(u)^2 \frac{dv}{du}\left(-  \sin(u) (\frac{dv}{du})^2 \right) + \cos(u)^2 \frac{d^2v}{du^2} $$

And Again:

$$0 =   \cos(u)^2 \frac{d^2v}{du^2} - 2 \sin (u) \frac{dv}{du} + \cos(u)^2 \sin(u) \left(\frac{dv}{du} \right)^3$$

But proceeding further seems... stuck.

Perhaps I made an algebraic mistake

Comment: Thank you for the detailed work, @frogeyedpeas!  I'm not entirely sure what the solution is supposed to look like; as you noted, it's quite messy.  Do you see any way the hint provided (in the initial question) makes things any better?

Comment: not off the top of my head, but perhaps a certain change of coordinate would be wise then